# How to know when CBPeripheral is no longer available

Tags: ios, swift, core-bluetooth

Is there a way to check if a CBPeripheral is actually still available to connect to?

I use `CBCentralManager` to scan for peripherals, it will return me my peripheral in `didDiscover peripheral:`.

If I turn the physical device that is the peripheral off and on again,`didDiscover peripheral:` does not get hit again.

Also if I call `centralManager.retrievePeripherals()` on a timer, the peripheral never disappears, despite being off for a prolonged period of time.

Answer (score 1):

When calling `scanForPeripherals` you pass on `CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey` as `true`:

```
centralManager.scanForPeripherals(withServices: yourUUIDs, options: [CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey: true])
```

This way `didDiscoverPeripheral` will be called many times over, which is normally used to update the RSSI, but if you keep track of the last time each peripheral was 'discovered' you can remove peripherals that have been inactive for too long.

If you keep peripherals that are already connected (e.g. with `retrieveConnectedPeripherals`) in the same array, you will also have to keep track of from which ones we should expect updates. I do this in this example by checking whether the RSSI is `nil` or not.

Example:

```
var peripherals = [(peripheral: CBPeripheral,  lastUpdate: Date!)]()
var inactivityTimer: Timer?


override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    centralManager.scanForPeripherals(withServices: yourUUIDs, options: [CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey: true])

    inactivityTimer?.invalidate() // prevent duplicates
    inactivityTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 2, target: self, selector: #selector(inactivityCheck), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

@objc func inactivityCheck() {
    // reversed because we're removing stuff
    for i in (0..<peripherals.count).reversed() {
        if peripherals[i].RSSI != nil && peripherals[i].lastUpdate.timeIntervalSinceNow < -2 { // 2s max inactivity
            peripherals.remove(at: i)
            tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}

func serialDidDiscoverPeripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : Any]?, RSSI: NSNumber?) {
    // check for duplicates
    if let i = peripherals.index(where: ({ $0.peripheral === peripheral })) {
        // update
        peripherals[i].RSSI = RSSI
        peripherals[i].lastUpdate = Date()
        tableView.reloadData()
    } else {
        // add
        peripherals.append((peripheral, advertisementData, RSSI, Date()))
        peripherals.sort { ($0.RSSI?.floatValue ?? 0) > ($1.RSSI?.floatValue ?? 0) } // optionally sort array to signal strength
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Edit: as for `centralManager.retrievePeripherals()` returning unavailable peripherals, I don't know how to fix that.